# How do I set path to access the owner(?) in Data Binding

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, data-binding

Sorry.. my english is so bad :'(

I wrote a messy xaml codes

```
<ScrollViewer>
<ItemsControl x:Name="REST0029" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuOfWeek}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DayOfWeek}" />
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Menus}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}" />
                                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Meals}">
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}" />
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>    
                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

And the below is my summary of class
MenuOfWeekPresenter

└ObservableCollection MenuOfWeek

MenuOfDay

└string DayOfWeek

└ObservableCollection menus

Menu

└string Type

└ObservableCollection meals

Meal

└string Name

└string Price

And I want to use {Binding Type} where,

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}" />
</StackPanel>
```

For example,

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}" />
</StackPanel>
```

like that...

please help me..:'(

Comment: Are you trying to say that you want to access Name and Price on Type?  Like Type.Name & Type.Price?

I'm not sure I understand you question, can you reframe it?

Comment: Sorry.. My native language is Korean.. so my English is so bad.. I reframed it.

Comment: If i understand it right then you try to write the Type before every meal not only once per Menu.

Comment: @BigL where do i write "Type"? in xaml? in class? if you meant 'in class', there is no ways to edit xaml files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this i think you would need to bind to the parents Datacontext and that is a bit tricky in Windows Phone 7 because it doesn't know FindAncestor you would have to use a Binding helper.

[Binding Helper Example](http://blog.thekieners.com/2010/09/08/relativesource-binding-with-findancestor-mode-in-silverlight/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what i want